# How to signal one always running command process to stop from another command process?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How would I go about having one command process send a command to another one?

Well, specifically a batch script. I have one that starts a service, and runs it 24 hours per day and 7 days per week in a command prompt window.

What I need is a batch script to send a command "stop" to the other command process.

I have looked this up online, but there's nothing too specific about this, and doesn't accomplish what I need.

Comment: What happens if you simply send the stop command to the service in a separate window?

Comment: Perhaps you are interested in the command `waitfor` to send out and wait for signals -- type `waitfor /?` for details...

Answer (score 1):

If the intent is to stop the other command prompt, why not just kill it?

[Taskkill](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb491009.aspx) could do this for you. For Eg:

```
Taskkill /PID 2704 /F
```

Comment: Nice technique loxxy, but I think the OP needs to automate this.

Comment: This can always go into another batch script

Comment: Yes, you're right, but how will the other script know the process ID of the other Window? Wouldn't that differ (unless of course he only has the same window and never turns off the computer)?

Comment: If he is smart, he'll give the window a custom title and kill the task based on that.

Comment: @itsols Well if you have a look at taskkill .. it doesn't just accept PID. You can have command prompt with a title, run it as a background service or if nothing else, even find out the PID by searching for the bat file name in the process list.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with Windows/DOS and I don't currently have access to it. +1 for your findings.

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps possible to use a file as indication for the nearly always running command process to terminate itself.

Example code for nearly always running batch file `AlwaysRunning.bat`:

```
@echo off

rem The example code in a nearly endless running loop just prints
rem a message and then waits 3 seconds to simulate process time
rem of other commands. Then the batch file checks if the file
rem used to signal a wanted exit of this batch file exists.
rem The file is deleted and command process exits in this case.

title %~n0

:Endless
echo %TIME% %~0 is running.
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 4 >nul
if exist "%TEMP%\ExitAlwaysRunning.tmp" (
    rem Other commands to execute before exit.
    del "%TEMP%\ExitAlwaysRunning.tmp"
    exit
)
goto Endless
```

The code for the other batch file `ExitRunning.bat` signaling with file `ExitAlwaysRunning.tmp` in directory for temporary files the batch file `AlwaysRunning.bat` to exit as soon as possible.

```
@echo off
rem Create in folder for temporary files an empty file as
rem indication for the always running batch task to exit.

copy NUL "%TEMP%\ExitAlwaysRunning.tmp" >nul

rem Define a maximum time of 10 seconds waiting for exit
rem of the other command process signaled by file just
rem created not existing anymore because deleted by the
rem nearly always running command process immediately
rem before exiting.

set "Timeout=10"

rem Check once per second if the other command process
rem deleted the temporary file immediately before exiting.

:WaitForExit
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -n 2 >nul
if not exist "%TEMP%\ExitAlwaysRunning.tmp" (
    echo.
    echo AlwaysRunning.bat deleted file and exited.
    goto ProcessExited
)
set /A Timeout-=1
if not %Timeout% == 0 (
    echo %Timeout% sec remaining on waiting for exit.
    goto WaitForExit
)

del "%TEMP%\ExitAlwaysRunning.tmp"
echo.
echo Command process processing AlwaysRunning.bat is either
echo not running or ignored the indication by file to exit.

rem Command tasklist could be used to find out if the other batch file
rem is still running and then taskkill could be used to kill the other
rem command process when not exiting within specified time. But this
rem should not happen if the initial timeout value is set correct.

:ProcessExited
rem Put here your other commands executed after nearly
rem always running command process terminated itself.

echo.
pause
```

Double click or run from within a command prompt window first `AlwaysRunning.bat`.

Then start in another command prompt window or with a double click  `ExitRunning.bat`.